# Vim, error about something that shouldn't exist

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map nerdtreetab to the n key.
When I press 'n' I get this error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1
```

I did at one point have

```
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1
```

in my .vimrc file, but I removed it, so why does this keep popping up?

I have mapped the toggling to:

```
map <Leader>n :NERDTreeFocusToggle "toggle nerdtree
```

Comment: Serious question: did you try turning it (Vim) off and on again?

Comment: I mean completely closing and re-opening vim

Comment: Don't add comments at end of line.

Comment: You said you pressed 'n' but your mapping is for `<Leader>n` which should be something like '\n'. Which is correct?

Comment: @Ben hmm no, just `n`, @Sato Katsura does that really break things? @ Andy doesn't doing `:q` to exit vim close it completely?

Comment: So it would seem your problem is that you did not actually map the desired command to 'n' but actually mapped it to something else. Since you pressed 'n' you just invoked the default behavior for 'n': jump to next search match.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of what `<Leader>` did, I'm 100% new to doing vim customisation, I'll add an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to some very helpful comments I now know the problem is the 
`<Leader>` in front of the `n` which makes the actual command `\n` rather than the `n` I wanted.

Changing it from

```
map <Leader>n :NERDTreeFocusToggle "toggle nerdtree
```

to

```
map n <plug>NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
```

fixed it, I also change it to use the plugin command so it directly activated the command rather then just place `NERDTreeFocusToggle` in the command line.

Thank you to the commenters, I will remember this for future reference.

For bonus points:

changed it to:

```
map <C-n> <plug>NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
```

so it's now ctrl + n